# Java: Regular Expression not matching?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract a special sequence out of a String using the following Regular Expression:

```
[(].*[)]
```

My Pattern should only match if the String contains `()` with text between them.

Somehow, i I create a new `Pattern` using `Pattern#compile(myString)` and then match the String using `Matcher matcher = myPattern.matcher();` it doesn't find anything, even though I tried it on [regexr.com](http://regexr.com) and it worked there.

My `Pattern` is a `static final` Pattern object in another class (I directly used `Pattern#compile(myString)`.

Example String to match:

```
save (xxx,yyy)
```

Comment: You should include part of your code

Comment: Please say whether you want to **match** or **extract**

Comment: What does _doesn't find anything_ mean? - Are you using _matches()_ or _find()_ ?

Comment: Also can you mention if you are using `matches()` or `find()`

Comment: Okay guys, was my fault, I fixed it as I literally forgot to use `find()`
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely problem here is your quantifier.

Since you're using greedy `*` with a combination of `.` for any character, your match will not delimit correctly as `.` will also match closing `)`.

Try using reluctant `[(].*?[)]`.

See quantifiers in [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

You can *also* escape parenthesis instead of using custom character classes, like so: `\\(` and `\\)`, but that has nothing to do with your issue.

**Also note** (thanks [esprittn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2123347/esprittn))

- The `*` quantifier will match 0+ characters, so if you want to restrict your matches to non-empty parenthesis, use `.+?` instead - that'll guarantee at least one character inside your parenthesis.

Comment: with [(].*?[)], empty parenthesis like ()  will be matched so replace * with +

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below code helps : its extracts the data between '(' & ')' including them .

```
String pattern = "\\(.*\\)";
    String line = "save(xx,yy)";
    Pattern TokenPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);

    Matcher m = TokenPattern.matcher(line);
    while (m.find()) {

        int start = m.start(0);
        int end = m.end(0);

        System.out.println(line.substring(start, end));

    }
```

to remove the brackets change 'start' to 'start+1' and 'end' to 'end-1' to change the bounding indexes of the sub-string being taken.